# write a UI that rerun the main method when click the button in java

Tags: java

I need a program that when I click the button, it will rerun the main(),aka, restart the program, but I am stuck on how to do it.  I actually do not know if it is possible to do this. Hope someone could help me out. Thank you.

```
package tst;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class callMain {
    private JButton buttons;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("how are you");

    }

    public callMain() {
        JButton button = new JButton("btn");
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // I want to rerun the program
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: `JButton` without `container` ?

Comment: Please read http://www.javatpoint.com/java-awt and http://www.javatpoint.com/event-handling-in-java

Comment: @Jerry06 Thanks for pointing out.  I skipped some details in my code ha.

Comment: Side point: yours is a terrible program design, and you should seriously re-think it. It suggests that you're still thinking in terms of linear console programming and are trying to shoehorn this paradigm into event-driven GUI programming, and when you do that, you end up with bad results that are rigid and brittle.

Comment: Instead, think in terms of event driven programming and program *state* -- reset the GUI's model back to its initial state on press of that button.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see thanks

Comment: I don't think we should answer much more than the direct question being asked. We could teach a full course on proper design patterns here, but this is not the appropriate place for it. Unless the question is specifically how the design can be improved, I think it is a waste to answer more than the simple question being posed. Almost any question ever posed on stackexchange could have improved design in some way, but that detracts from people actually getting answers that they are looking for.

Comment: @JeremyGurr  Nobody forces you to answer any question. If you are going to answer the question, then it is a waste of time for both you and ME.

Answer (score -1):

Do this when you want to call your main method again:

```
callMain.main(new String[] {});
```

Or even easier, if you are in the callMain class:

```
main(new String[] {});
```